# How to design gain based on input voltage and ADC voltage range?

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, biopotential

What are the parameters to consider when designing gain amplification whether it be 2- or 1-stage (why one or the other?) when given an input and an ADC? I see for the same kind of signal (biosignal) people use a variety of different gains from like 20 to 2000. How do you account for noise level for the ADC to function, because that gets amplified too.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question, but I will try to give some hints here.

The expected amplitude of biosignals can be very different. You may receive in the range of 10 mV from a muscle, up to 1 mV from eye movement detection or just some 0.1 µV from brain activity. So you have to define the Vpp range you want to measure first.

At the input you have an AC coupled differential input stage to remove any DC voltage between the electrodes. It has a very high input resistance and the main task is to produce a low impedance signal relative to the circuit GND. The gain is low here because all unwanted signals (e.g. mains artefacts and noise) are amplified here as well and the amplifier should not clip.

Then you need a filter to get rid of higher frequency noise and low frequencies introduced by body movement or electrode pressure changes. The final amplifier should process only the desired signal components.

Often there is a special notch filter to suppress 50 and 60 Hz.

After the filters you place the amplifier, that must match the ADC input range.

Let us assume you want to measure +/- 1mV and the ADC range is 0..3.3 V, you need a gain of 1650. The differential input amplifier will e.g. work with a gain of 20, the filter typically has no gain and the 3rd stage has a gain of 82.5. There may be good reasons, depending on the application, to assign the gain values in a different manner.

In some applications the 3rd stage is divided into 2 separate stages with a high pass fiter between them to avoid saturation and clipping.

Comment: There are other intricacies that I don't quite have a grasp on like if one chooses too high of an input gain it could saturate the signal. What does that statement mean by that?

Comment: @Roshan The used electrodes together with contact liquid form a galvanic cell, that produce a DC voltage up to, say 200 mV. All electrodes produce this voltage and so this cancels out to some amount. On top of this DC voltage is the small AC voltage that you want to measure. But, if electrode wires are moved or the mechanical force on the electrodes changes, there is a signal change with an amplitude far above the desired AC signal. If your first stage gain is too big, the output will reach a supply rail and you lose the information of the small AC signal.